# Sub query to count users

Tags: subquery

I am having trouble with adding a sub query to the following query -

```
SELECT state 
     FROM users
     ORDER BY state
```

**Output:**

```
 Alabama
 Alaska
 Arizona
 ...
```

I would like to include the number of users from each state so I can output it 
like:

```
Alabama (12)
Alaska (4)
Arizona (25)
```

ANSWER:

```
  $query=mysqli_query($connect,"select state, 
     count(*) AS count from users 
     GROUP BY state");  

        while($rows=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query))
        {

        echo $rows['state'];
        echo $rows['count'];
     }
```

I didn't realize I had to name count(*) AS count so I could output it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is do a "group by" in the query.

The way it would work is like this:

```
select state, count(id)
from users
group by state
order by state
```

what this will do is group the records by the state and show how many records exist for that state.

Comment: Is that a sub query or the whole query?